# Magento Soap client is not working on https

Tags: php, magento, soap, https, wsdl

I have facing issue on `Magento soap api connection whenever try to use https as secure url`.

My magento system `version CE 1.7 and soap version 1`.

System Url setup is

```
Secure url is  https://www.example.com/
Unsecured  is  http://www.example.com/
```

**When i am changed secure to http://www.example.com/(With out https)**

Then the soap client is working properly.

```
Also,when secure is https://www.example.com ,it throw below error:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl
```

My code is

```
try{

$cli = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl');
$session = $cli->login('marketplace_usr', 'ezvendorplus');
$result = $cli->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', 10887);
var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is server site issue.Hosting provider is resolved the issue by

```
add a ssl vhost on private ip for www.example.com and reload apache
and also made a host file entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Check is php_openssl extension enabled. If not - enable it.